# Crashlytics: no crashes for the same bundleId but different project

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I have added Crashlytics for previous app and it's working. Now we developed a completely new app but will reuse the same bundle identifier (total upgrade). This project has two targets - normal and development. Normal has old bundle identifier, new one has a slightly different bundle identifier. Strange thing is we can see crashes for development target build, but for normal one not. Why we don't see crashes for the same bundle identifier (but different code base)? IMHO crashlytics should just care about bundlerId which in my case is the same. Version number is higher than old app version. I use crashlytics via CocoaPods.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem.  Crashlytics does not pick up the re-used bundle IDs.

Comment: @Reed, Nop, still haven't found solution.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a Crashlytics bug.

I solved my problem by raising a support request to Fabric/Crashlytics team.  The dudes over there are very reachable.

However you need to register on their forum.  Here is my (solved)support ticket.
https://twittercommunity.com/t/fabric-crashlytics-stuck-verifying-installation-with-bundle-id-that-had-been-deleted/36188

Comment: Thanks @Reed. I'v created a topic on Twitter dashboard: https://twittercommunity.com/t/ios-sdk-how-to-check-why-crashlytics-is-not-sending-crash-info-http-api-calls/36501 . Lets see how they are responsive.

Comment: Nop it didn't. I reported them on forums and even via Fabric.io website but they are not responsive at all. I tried all other solutions and here's the last remaining thing I'm trying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298479/how-to-disable-auto-downloadopen-of-fabric-app-on-ci-build-server