# How to disable auto download+open of Fabric.app on CI build server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

We are unable to get our Fabric+Crashlytics working via teamcity CI. The problem is we don't get crash reports in fabric dashboard. So far I'v tried all the possible solutions and still nothing helps. The only remaining thing to try is to make sure Xcode is closed and Fabric.app is not installed on build machine. However, as soon as build is started to be created, build machine auto downloads and opens Fabric.app (I even tried to close it several times during build process but it stills pops and building is stuck if app is not opened). Wondering what is causing this auto download and why build is still requiring it. Here's how our pods file looks like:

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.2' #also tried with pod 'Fabric/Core', '~> 1.2'
pod 'Fabric/Crashlytics', '~> 1.2'
```

The crashes are seen in fabric dashboard if I install app on device via xcode.  BUT when we create a CI build, deploy and download the app from hockeyapp (or any other distribution provider) then app is not sending crash reports. Dsyms are not missing (no warning, hidden dsym upload link is not complaining about missing dsyms). CI build log doesn't contain any errors. A new app version is created on fabric dashboard after each our teamcity build (this means post script is able to send dsym and tell fabric about new version). I triple checked my key and secret inside plist file and post script. This is how my post script looks like:

```
./Pods/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run <API_key> <Secret>
```

This is how we start fabric as a last line in AppDelegate

```
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
```

Any ideas? I ran out of ideas and will probably try to submit the app to the app store directly via Xcode (not through application loader) and will probably look for other crash reporting tool for next release.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. It sounds very odd that the auto-download is happening on the build server. Keeping XCode.app closed with Fabric.app not installed is definitely the right approach. Just to be sure Fabric.app is completely removed from the CI box, not in Trash or Downloads?

Comment: Awesome to hear that did the trick. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MikeB from Fabric, I was finally able to get crashes. I'm not sure why fabric.app was getting downloaded and opened, but the thing is it's not downloaded and opened by default after restarting our build server :)

So it looks like the problem was in having installed and opened fabric.app on build server. And now after it's completely removed, we are able to get crashes.